# Question : How to solve a functional differential equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Can we solve some functional (differential) equation like : $y(x)=y'(2x)$ or $f(g(x))=f'(x)g'(x)$ ?

I know we can't solve these (hard) equations : $y(\sqrt{x^2-3x})=y'(2x-3)-x$ :)
Sure there exists some we can solve, but which ones ?

Comment: An equation such as $y'(x)=y(Ax),$ where $A$ is some real number, can always be solved by using the power series method. This is because the equation guarantees that $y$ is analytic somewhere, since the nth derivative is given by $y(A^nx).$ The first equation you gave can be rewritten as $y'(x)=y(x/2),$ so it falls under this class of functions. I cannot help much with the rest.

Comment: @Angel How to use the power series method ? I don't know about this ! Thanks

Comment: Let $$y(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n,$$ with $$y'(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^n.$$ Solve for $a_n$ to get your power series answer.